# How to make a Observable/Promisse to wait for other promisse to happen first?

Tags: javascript, angular, promise, ngrx

I have a nrgx effect in angular, where i am pushing promisses to then resolve them with a Promisse.all.

But one promisse takes some time to run because its fetching data from the server, but the problem is that the Promisses.all runs before that one particular promisse ends so i dont get all the results that i need.

My question is how to make so that the Promisse.all waits first for my big time promisse?

Code:

```
effect = this.actions$.ofType(projectAction.GETDATA).
    .switchMap(([action,state])) => {
     
    // this is the function that needs to be completed before the Promisses.all
    this.getNameData().then( data => {
      promisses.push( this.dataService.getAllNameData(data))
    })
   
    names.forEach((name) => {
       promisses.push( this.dataService.getAllNameData(name))
    })

    return Observable.fromPromisse(
      Promisse.all(promisses).then((results) => {
            //data logic
              return new dataAction.getDataSucess(data)
        })
    );
}


// function: 
getNameData() {
  return Promise.resolve().then(() => this.getNameFromDatabase() // this returns data from the server)
}
```

I hope my explanation was clear. I am with hours trying to find a solution for this

Comment: `Promise` is spelled with a single `s`. Calling `Promisse.all` won't work

Comment: Use `combineLatest` on Observables instead

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve that by [fork join](https://rxjs.dev/api/index/function/forkJoin) .
Wrap each promise in a [from](https://rxjs.dev/api/index/function/from) and put in a global fork.
Fork Join by definition waits for all requests to be completed